# Foreaching an array and matching?

Tags: php, arrays

How would I iterate through an array (300+ items, imported via simplexml) and pull out every item that has a certain $x->channel->item->title and put that into a different array?

I can't make heads or tails of the haystack needle thing or how to push arrays

Say I have an array (needle) like: array("3332","3300","3493","8380") and I want to match if any of those appear through the big array (haystack). How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate over your big array, and check for the value of `$x->channel->item->title`. If it meets your criteria, push it into the new array:

```
$theArray; // Your 300+ array
$lookFor = array('firstthing', 'second thing', 'third thing');
$newArray = array();

foreach($theArray as $x) {
    if ( in_array($x->channel->item->title, $lookFor) ) {
        array_push($newArray, $x);
    }
}
```

Comment: how would i match multiple? do i do == 'firstthing' || == ' second thing' || == 'third thing'?

Comment: you can use in_array(), see example below

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($yourArray as $key => $value)
{
  //do your things with $key and/or $value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying from Joseph's loop, you can do:

```
$theArray; // Your 300+ array
$newArray = array();
$matchArray = array("3332","3300","3493","8380");

foreach($theArray as $x) {
    if (in_array($x->channel->item->title, $matchArray)) {
        array_push($newArray, $x);
    }
}
```

Check out in_array() at http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: is this preventing duplicates if there are no duplicates in the first place? i was trying some lopsided insane method that resulted in each of the four showing up four times because i don't know how to loop, lol

Comment: If there are duplicates in your $matchArray, in_array() will simply return true, so there should be no duplicates.